# SQL Server 2008 R2, second connection fails after creating a new database

Tags: .net, ado.net, sql-server-2008-r2

This has just started happening recently, the code has been running fine for several years and is unchanged.  The sequence of events is this:

1. Using a `System.Data.SqlConnection`, we connect to master and execute some scripts in sequence that create a new database, create the schema objects (including the `aspnet_*` membership objects), and insert some seed data.
2. Immediately after this, we run an .NET Membership provider operation to create a user.

Recently, we have begun failing sometimes at step two. In some instances, it thinks that the database does not exist and fails the connection attempt. In others, it connects but fails to find the `aspnet_CheckSchemaVersion` stored procedure (presumably this is the first object it tries to use.)

There is nothing asynchronous about this, but it seems like the second connection (from the Membership provider) is not always seeing the current state of the database. It always completes without error when the SQL Server and the running application are on the same machine. It fails regularly, but not always, when the SQL Server is remote. There are no explicit transactions involved.

Any ideas?

Thanks